# React switch between hidden and visible value of array on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with toggling between elements in React.

Here I have a small array of html elements as an example:

```
  const question1 = <div className="question_section">
    Question 1
    <div className="answer_section">
      <p>Answer 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  const question2 = <div className="question_section">
    Question 2
    <div className="answer_section">
      <p>Answer 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  const question3 = <div className="question_section">
    Question 3
    <div className="answer_section">
      <p>Answer 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  const question = [question1, question2, question3]
```

I want all of them to be hidden at the start and being able to switch between visible and hidden on click. My problem is that I do not understand how to create proper function where each element of array will have condition "isVisible". Like "question1 click -> question1 is visible, all other stay hidden until they are not clicked -> question1 clicked once more and hidden and all other questions remain with their state until they are clicked".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding onClick on the view/hide button and using the question id to change its display.

Hope it helps:

```js
export function Test() {
  const handleToggleView = (questionIndex) => {
    const questionElement = document.getElementById(`question-${questionIndex}-content`);
    if(questionElement) {
      const previousDisplay = questionElement.style.display;
      questionElement.style.display = previousDisplay === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  }

  const questions = new Array(3).fill(0).map((_, index) => (
    <div className="question_section">
      <div id={`question-${index}-content`} style={{ display: 'none' }}>
        Question {index + 1}
        <div className="answer_section">
          <p>Answer {index + 1}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => handleToggleView(index)}>
        view/hide
      </button>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      {questions}
    </div>
  );
}
```